# Trying to understand a Taylor expansion in a book.

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am having difficulty understanding how a Taylor series is generated in an example. I am familiar with the Taylor equation being of the form:

$$
f(a)+{\frac{f^{\prime}(a)}{1!}}(x-a)+{\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(a)}{2!}}(x-a)^{2}+{\frac{f^{\prime\prime\prime}(a)}{3!}}(x-a)^{3}+\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}}(x-a)^{n}.
$$

I am copying the equation and its Taylor expansion below. What am I missing here? I feel confused because the function $I_T$ seems to be defined using the function itself.  How does the author exactly obtain $\frac{dI_t}{dv}$?

The equations and explanations below are from the textbook, I merely copied them:

---

$$
I_{\mathrm{T}}(v)=I_{\mathrm{T}}(v+m \sin (\Omega t))
$$

In the equation above requires that $\Omega<\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is the line width of absorption lines. Through Taylor series expansion of the equation above, there is
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{\mathrm{T}}(v+m \sin (\Omega t))= & I_{\mathrm{T}}(v)+(m \sin \Omega t) \frac{\mathrm{d} I_T}{\mathrm{~d} v}+\left(\frac{m^2 \sin ^2 \Omega t}{2 !}\right) \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 I_T}{\mathrm{~d} v^2} \\
& +\left(\frac{m^3 \sin ^3 \Omega t}{3 !}\right) \frac{\mathrm{d}^3 I_T}{\mathrm{~d} v^3}+\cdots=\left[I_T(v)+\frac{m^2}{4} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 I_T}{\mathrm{~d} v^2}+\cdots\right] \\
& +\sin \Omega t\left[m \frac{\mathrm{d} I_T}{\mathrm{~d} v}+\frac{m^3}{8} \sin ^2 \Omega t \frac{d^3 I_T}{\mathrm{~d} v^3}+\cdots\right] \\
& +\cos 2 \Omega t\left[-\frac{m^2}{4} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 I_T}{\mathrm{~d} v^2}+\cdots\right]+\cdots
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Is it indeed $I_{\mathrm{T}}(v)=I_{\mathrm{T}}(v+m \sin (\Omega t))$ what appears in the book?

Comment: The Taylor series you mention in the first line represents $f(x) = f(a + (x-a)) = f(a+h)$, where we introduce $h:= (x-a)$. So it lets you describe $f$ for small distances $h$ away from $a$. In the example below, $h=m\sin(\Omega t)$, and $a=v$. It does not appear to make use of the functional equation $I_{\mathrm{T}}(v)=I_{\mathrm{T}}(v+m \sin (\Omega t))$.

Comment: It seems the author does not need to know the derivative $dI_T/dv$ - the expansion is valid under the assumption that the derivatives exist. If they use it to discuss theoretical properties, it might be sufficient.

Comment: @Gary Yes, here is the screenshot from the source: https://i.imgur.com/E1JkxVP.jpeg

Comment: I belive the correct expression should be $I_{\mathrm{T}}(v)\approx I_{\mathrm{T}}(v+m \sin (\Omega t))$.